# Stop my Mac from downloading Apple TV content

Tags: itunes, appletv

I have an Apple TV where I subscribe to Seasons for various shows and watch them on my TV. The problem is that my Mac is also downloading the same,  storing it on the hard drive.

These are very large files, and I don't want to store them locally or use my bandwidth to download them.

How do I stop this from happening? Is there a setting in iTunes to make it stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have "download pre-orders when available" disabled in your iTunes preferences by going to iTunes > Preferences under the Store tab. Then, untick If you have this selected in itunes you are telling itunes to download all new shows that you watch. If you untick it new future shows will not download.

Answer (score 0):

In iTunes, go to File > Preferences. Then click on the "Store" tab, and try turning "Download pre-orders when available" off.